# How do I add padding or margin and change font in CSS? (Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Well this is my website, defensionem.com (It is a website dedicated to men and women and machines related to the military.)

I want the site to be readable to everyone, I have stumbled upon a rather tricky issue.

http://defensionem.com/2015/09/13/us-military-demo-2/

In the above page, I would like the article text (including the Share, About and Comments) and the sidebar to be pushed into the centre of the screen.

I tried padding and using this it worked.

I am unable to change the font though.

```
.article-body-wrap{
padding-left:200px;
}

.sidebar_right-sidebar_col-sm-3{
padding-right:200px;
}
```

This worked but I tried changing the font which did not. (It changed the font for everything).

```
.body-text_clearfix{
font-size:32px;
}
```

Above yielded no result. How do I change the font of only the text? Which element tag/class do I use to change it?

Answer (score 2):

You have an error:

```
.sidebar_right-sidebar_col-sm-3{
  padding:right:200px;
  //-----^
}
```

Change it to `padding-right`:

```
.sidebar_right-sidebar_col-sm-3 {
  padding-right:200px;
  //-----^
}
```

You can change it to a different font by using `font-family` in it:

```
.className {font-family: Arial;}
.className {font-family: Times;}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I change the font? I am unable to change it.

Comment: @DineshGupta Font family (name) or size?

Answer (score -1):

I cant help with the padding but for the font you want to give the text you want to change a class like so

```
<body>
<h1>Example Text</h1>
<p class="Potato">Text With Font</p>
</body>
```

And Then for your CSS

```
body > .Potato{
    font-size:32px;
}
```

Comment: that's not quite right. It should be `body > .Potato{ font-size:32px; }` or just `.Potato{ font-size:32px; }`, but `body > Potato{ font-size:32px; }` will not work.